# Setup iOS Local Webserver on an iphone/ipad? http://localhost/ like XAMPP

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xampp, localhost

I want localhost xampp like server on my ipad/iphone..

where i can visit http://localhost/ to test my local web app on the iphone/ipad..

kindly help!!

PS: I dont know if CocoaHTTPServer is suitable for this job, but don't know how to install it on my ios device either.